# Custom request if field name are different? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Using Laravel 7
Updated Topic because issue is now with type Radio

Table name users. has column 'username'

my input field:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.store') }}" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="">
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary active">
<input type="radio" name="paki" value="1" checked> Active
</label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="paki" value="2"> Inactive
</label>
 <button type="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
```

In Controller Tried:

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    $req->validate([
    'username' => 'required|unique:users',
    ]);
    $users = new Users();
    $users->username = $req->username;       
    $users->status = $req->paki;
    $users->save();        
    return redirect()->route('list.users');
}
```

dd($req->all());

```
`array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "cnLMS8sYWOCZbP24QhQ3QoHXLZguyRUk0Cx8U1Tj"
  "username" => "jhon"  
  "paki" => "1"
]`
```

Comment: What is in $users? Show full code instead of single lines

Comment: We need to see some more code. If $users is an instance of  `User:class` this should work, can't help you without more info...

Comment: you can not have two elements with the same name, I think you do, change the name `paki` to `pakiRadio`

Comment: After your edit you changed the entire question, before the update you had a text input named "paki", is your new question about the radio buttons in the same form? Because if so, your problem is that you have multiple inputs with the same name of "paki", so it's your controller will always retrieve only one of them.

Comment: paki is used only for radio, other are different.

Comment: @user8625968 show the whole form and the controller

Comment: @user8625968 what you get when you do `dd(request()->all());` in your controller.

Comment: What is `Users()` ? If its the default `User::class` model it should be `$user = new User;`

Comment: The request is working correctly, the problem must be in $users like @Gamopo stated in one of the answers, show us the when you import `Users` at the top of your contoller file.

Comment: Could anyone try? its does not store in database.

Comment: @user8625968 What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

for this HTML with name of 'paki';

```php
<input type="text" name="paki">
```

You can use either `input` or `get` to get the request value.

```php
$users->username = $request->input('paki');
//or
$users->username = $request->get('paki');
```

for radio

```html
            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary active">
                <input type="radio" name="pakiRadio" value="1" checked> Active
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="pakiRadio" value="2"> Inactive
            </label>
```

```php
$users->status = $request->input('pakiRadio');
//or
$users->status = $request->get('pakiRadio');
```

Comment: How is this any different that what the OP already tried? It's just a different way of doing `$users->username = $request->paki;`.

Comment: @RobertKujawa because you can get the post value with either `input` or `get` , you can not directly access a property on `request`

Comment: You can 'Retrieving Input Via Dynamic Properties' just like the OP is doing, it's in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: @user8625968 it's the same. but you can not have the name attribute the same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your field by using:
`$request->paki` but be careful, paki will be a single value and you haven't posted the definition of `$users` but being plural I could guess that's a list and not a value.

Comment: users is table name.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 6//7
Short format works and not required to include `input/get`

```
$users->username = $request->('paki');
```

I just fix the issue `composer dump-autoload`